# Losing single quotes in .bash_profile

Tags: macos, terminal, alias, browser-sync, bash

i am a new in work with terminal.app. I am using the browser-sync to create a server. I give to alias in .bash_profile this code:

```
alias server='browser-sync start --server --no-notify --directory 'desktop/project/src' --files "*.html, css/*.css, js/*.js"'
```

But when i try to call "server" i see that alias has lost single quotes after --directory

```
alias server='browser-sync start --server --no-notify --directory desktop/project/src --files "*.html, css/*.css, js/*.js"'
```

And i can't start my server from desired directory. Can you help me please. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes (of the same type) don't nest. You're trying to put a single-quotes inside a single-quoted string, and this just isn't possible. Thus, the shell parses your alias command into these sections:

1. An unquoted section: `alias server=`
2. A single-quoted section: `'browser-sync start --server --no-notify --directory '`
3. Another unquoted section: `desktop/project/src`
4. Another single-quoted section: `' --files "*.html, css/*.css, js/*.js"'`

You can nest single-quotes inside a double-quoted string, or vice versa, and it's even possible to nest double-quotes inside a double-quoted string by escaping the inner quotes. But I don't think that's the actual problem here; the single-quotes that're getting "lost" wouldn't actually do anything if they were there. That is, these two commands:

```
browser-sync start --server --no-notify --directory 'desktop/project/src' --files "*.html, css/*.css, js/*.js"
browser-sync start --server --no-notify --directory desktop/project/src --files "*.html, css/*.css, js/*.js"
```

do *exactly* the same thing. The single-quotes around the directory path tell the shell not to interpret any shell metacharacters in that string, but since there are no shell metacharacters there, they have no effect at all (and are removed before being passed to the `browser-sync` command.

There has to be something else going wrong. It's possible you're running it from the wrong directory (`desktop/project/src` is a relative path, and will probably only work if you're in your home directory at the time) or it might be case sensitive (the directory is named "Desktop", not "desktop"), or it might be something else. But it's not the quoting in the alias.